# Body cannot contain "i.stack.imgur.com"

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, images

I get an error when I'm trying to make a post on StackOverflow that says

> Body cannot contain "i.stack.imgur.com".

Why is this happening and how do I get around it?  The site generated all these URLs by me pasting an image from my clipboard. This post here includes that URL, and the site isn't complaining.

[image]

Comment: I keep getting this error in other posts on SO as well, even if I add an image using the GUI.

Comment: Yup, me too. Yet the images are there if you put the url in your address bar.

Comment: @Taryn, I just tested this. Also applies to comments on SO as well.

Answer (score 15):

We... somehow ended up with a blacklist entry blocking the URL in all input fields.

I've removed it and am gonna do some digging into what happened there. As far as I can tell, it wasn't added manually, which suggests some other system we have is misbehaving.

Comment: I just tried resubmitting the post and I still get that error. Does it take time for this change to apply?

Comment: after my second to reattempt, it worked. Leaving the above comment because it may help diagnose the problem

Comment: @DanielKaplan Yeah, my first attempt at removing it failed (with a success message), so it turns out we have another bug to fix. ‍♂️ https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vxyl.png

Comment: Evidently this was my fault - I had _no idea_ we had code that does this (from a seemingly unrelated action). It's safe to say we'll be adding some guards.